# How to bulk collect in Oracle into a table of custom type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, collections, oracle11g

I have this:

```
TYPE record_flags IS RECORD (   
      is_delete    map_calculation.is_delete%TYPE,
      is_editable  map_calculation.is_editable%TYPE   
   );
TYPE table_flags IS TABLE OF record_flags INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT IS_DELETE, IS_EDITABLE BULK COLLECT INTO table_flags.is_delete, table_flags.is_editable
FROM (table and where clause...)
```

The query returns 2 rows exactly always. One row has 2 fields. I need to save them all into variable(s). But Oracle is swearing at me for this syntax (underlines just before word bulk). Hope it is clear what i want to achieve. what is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare table_flags like below and try

```
 table_flags1 table_flags;

 SELECT IS_DELETE, IS_EDITABLE BULK COLLECT INTO table_flags1
 FROM your_table
```

Comment: "Into clause is expected"

Comment: Thnaks! My bad!